# Google Inapp Error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I implemented Google inapp purchase in my application. For testing i used

1. Build signed apk with your own production keys
2. Upload signed apk to Android Market Developer Console
3. Upload signed apk to device
4. Added my public key from Market to my application
5. Uploaded my signed and in-app-purchasing-enabled apk to market (unpublished)
6. Created an in-app item in the market console (published)
7. Added a test user account to my profile

but when I test the inapp it says "the item you requested is not available for purchase".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass the product id like this...

```
BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "your product id");
```

and make your product published in the market..

Comment: but i am sending like this   /**
     * purchase requests.
     */
   <b> private String mPayloadContents = null;<b>    mBillingService = new BillingService();
        mBillingService.setContext(this);
 if (!mBillingService.requestPurchase("ID", mPayloadContents)) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
        }

Comment: Thnks for you response...when i publish my app then inapp test works fine and makes full purchase but...i cant test through test ACCOUNT...AND MY BOSS WANT ME TO TEST THROUGH TEST ACCOUNT

Comment: you have to make one signed apk of your app and put in the market as a draft (unpublished)..This way you can test..

Comment: You can cancel your in app purchases in Google Merchant account.

Comment: will you plz guide me...it worked with my test account and didnot gave me error"the item you requested is not available for purchase"..but when i published my purchase price...and then it asked to give details of credit card....is it fine way to test with TEST account

Comment: No if you want to test in app purchases you should make real purchases with credit card, just make price 0,01 $ and after purchases you can cancel your in app purchases in Google Merchant account.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change an in-app product item in the market console from unpublished to published.